# Pass variable values from child XUL window to parent  XUL window using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, xul

I have a function to get the values of the selected check-box from the xul file(Lets say tree.xul). In another XUL file has the text-box where I want to pass the values(label values) of the selected check-box(Lets say textbox.xul).

Originally I'm opening my "tree.xul" file from "textbox.xul" file. When I select the check box values and click on the button to pass the values to an another xul file("textbox.xul").

I have a text-box in "textbox.xul" file, I want to pass the values of the check-box to this text-box.

```
 <textbox id="ali" value=""/>
 <button label="Contacts" onclick="DisplayContacts();"/>
```

In my script I'm trying like this but it's not working and also I have included this small piece of code function

> window.close();

to close the window("tree.xul") after passing the values.

Do i have to use an array to store all the values of the variable?

I'm trying using the explanation from Mozilla dialog but it's not working.

```
 function get() { // check the alignment on a number of cells in a table.
var table = document.getElementById("box");
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{
     var cell = cells[i];
        if(cell.checked) {
            alert(cell.getAttribute("label"));
            var x = cell.getAttribute("label");
            x  = window.arguments[0];
            // or cell.label
        }
 }

  window.close();

}
```

This is the code for the check-box values created dynamically:

```
function choose()
{
//alert('hi');
  var tree = document.getElementById('myTodoListTree');
  for (var i = 0; i < tree.view.rowCount; i++) {
   if (tree.view.getCellValue(i, tree.columns.getColumnAt(0)) == 'true'){


var empty = " ";
var contact = (tree.view.getCellText(i, tree.columns.getNamedColumn("name"))+ empty+
tree.view.getCellText(i, tree.columns.getNamedColumn("lastname"))+ empty+ "Contacts:");

var ggmail = tree.view.getCellText(i, tree.columns.getNamedColumn("gmail"));
var yyahoo = tree.view.getCellText(i, tree.columns.getNamedColumn("yahoo"));


  var existingEl  = document.getElementById('box');
  var capt   = document.createElement('groupbox');
  existingEl.appendChild(capt);
  var captionEl   = document.createElement('caption');
  capt.appendChild(captionEl);
  captionEl.setAttribute('label', contact );
  captionEl.setAttribute('style', 'color: blue;');


  var existing  = document.getElementById('box');
  var checkbox   = document.createElement('checkbox');
  capt.appendChild(checkbox);
  checkbox.setAttribute('label', ggmail );
  checkbox.setAttribute('style', 'color: green;');

  var existing  = document.getElementById('box');
  var checkbox   = document.createElement('checkbox');
  capt.appendChild(checkbox);
  checkbox.setAttribute('label', yyahoo);
  checkbox.setAttribute('style', 'color: green;');

    }
  }
  return arr;

}
```

Here the user select the check-box in the "tree.xul" file and I have button("function get()") to add the values to the text-box in the "texbox.xul" window.

This is the function to open the tree.xul from the text-box.xul file:

```
function DisplayContacts()
{
var returnValues = { out: null };
window.openDialog("chrome://hello/content/sundayevening2.xul","sundayevening2","", returnValues);
}
```

Please help me to pass the values to the text-box in another XUL window.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use something like this: [Passing extra parameters to the dialog in XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.openDialog#Passing_extra_parameters_to_the_dialog)

This provides a simple way to pass values across xul files.

For your problem you can do something like this in the textbox.xul. This will open tree.xul along with the extra parameter *returnValues*:

```
var returnValues = { out: null };
window.openDialog("tree.xul", "tree", "modal", returnValues);
```

*Note `modal` is a must.*

Next in your tree.xul, store all the values (lets call it *x*) that you want to pass to textbox.xul as below:

```
window.arguments[0].out = x
```

*Note window.argument[0] refers to returnValues*

Now you can access the values of *x* (which is the names of the labels in your case) in textbox.xul as follows:

```
var labels = returnValues.out;
```

Basically,

1. You pass a parameter to the child window at the time of opening it.
2. Then in the child window, fill the parameter with the values that wish to pass back to
   the parent window and then close the child window.
3. Now back in the parent window you can access the parameter that you passed to the child and it contains information updated by the child window.

Comment: It's seems like very difficult to understand to me.

Comment: Updated to add more explanation

Comment: First line and second code is fine. I couldn't understand the third code. I want to update the value to the text-box in the parent window.if(cells[i].checked)
var status = (cells[i].getAttribute("label"));
    var emails = status+";";
        alert(emails);
        var emails = x;
      x  = window.arguments[0];
      var x = returnValues.out;
window.close(); Please check this.

Comment: do you wish to update the textbox in real time as the user check or unchecks or only when the user closes the tree.xul?Also can you tell me in your code which values you wish to pass back? And why do you close the window within the loop?

Comment: When user the select the check-boxes then click on the button(function get()) in the "tree.xul" file and the selected checkbox label values must update to the textbox in the "textbox.xul" file. I have updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: Ok! In your get() within the loop do something like: `x = x + cell.getAttribute("label") + ",";` This will create a string of labels that were checked. After the loop is over do: `window.argument[0].out = x;` This will set the value of out to the string. Next in the `DisplayContacts()` add this line at the end to set the value of the textbox to the string: `document.getElementById('text-box').value = returnValues.out;`

Comment: I have changed as per your suggestion: for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{
  var cell = cells[i];
        if(cell.checked) {
            alert(cell.getAttribute("label"));
            var x = x + cell.getAttribute("label") + ";";
            
        }window.argument[0].out = x;
 }
     window.close();
} 
function DisplayContacts()
{
var returnValues = { out: null };
window.openDialog("chrome://hello/content/sundayevening2.xul","sundayevening2","", returnValues);
document.getElementById('ali').value = returnValues.out;
} Still it's not working.

Comment: I think, it should be  window.arguments[0].out = x. Now i can get the value of the selected check-box and it's closing the window but the values are not passed to the text-box in the text-box xul window.

Comment: Can you alert the value of `returnValues.out` after the open dialog statement to check what me be wrong?

Comment: In the child window after assigning the variable to x, i can alert window.arguments[0].out and it's working. I have added this in the display contacts() :alert(returnValues.out); it's giving me the null values. I thing there is some problem with the looping in the child window, that may be deleting the arguments before passing to the parent window, what do you think?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the loop. To check just check the value of window.arguments[0].out just before window.close() ie. after the loop is over.

Comment: function get() { // check the alignment on a number of cells in a table.

var table = document.getElementById("box");
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{
  var cell = cells[i];
        if(cell.checked) {
            //alert(cell.getAttribute("label"));
            var x = (cell.getAttribute("label") + ";");
            alert(x);
        }
            window.arguments[0].out = x;
            //alert(window.arguments[0].out);
 }
          window.close();
} There is no returnValues.out in this function. Shall we do a chat? Thank you.

Comment: If you have some time, I can send you the whole file, you can check in your system.

Comment: Sure! email me at amulyakhare@gmail.com

Comment: Amulya Khare: Email sent & waiting for your response. if you have nay doubt please ping me in gmail chat.

Comment: I have a question? I have menu list in a dialog window(child) and I want to pass values from the parent window(Xul tree) to the child dialog window. Is it the same principle that what we have used in this case?

Comment: ah, i wanna give +2 to this answer, and is this the only way of data exchange between 2 xul windows?