# Close Prompt alert box automatically with 10Seconds in XUL JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timer, xul, alert, prompt

This is my prompt alert box function in XUL:
function promptBoxes()

```
{
var prompts = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"]
                        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPromptService);

var check = {value: false};                  // default the checkbox to false

var flags = prompts.BUTTON_POS_0 * prompts.BUTTON_TITLE_Ok+
            prompts.BUTTON_POS_1 * prompts.BUTTON_TITLE_IS_STRING;

var button = prompts.confirmEx(null, "Title of this Dialog", "What do you want to do?",
                               flags, "", "Cancel", "", null, check);
// 0, 1, or 2.

}
```

I have taken the above function from this website:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPromptService#alertCheck_example

How could I close this box automatically within 10seconds(with display message: this prompt box will close  in 1O seconds and display the timer in the box itself)?

How can position this box to shown at the corner of the system?

I don't find any timer details in Mozilla prompt service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the build in prompt but you can easily do so with a custom prompt window.

1) Create a XUL dialog *alert_prompt.xul* as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css" type="text/css"?>
<dialog id="alertprompt" title="Alert"
   xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
   buttons="accept,cancel"
   buttonlabelcancel="Cancel"
   buttonlabelaccept="Save"
   height="140"
   width="250"
   ondialogaccept="return alert_prompt.doOK();"
   ondialogcancel="return alert_prompt.doCancel();">

   <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://hello/content/alert_prompt.js"/>

    <dialogheader title="Timer Alert Prompt"/>
    <label id="result" value="This prompt will close in 10 seconds." align="center"/>
</dialog>
```

2) Create a Javascript file for this XUL window *alert_prompt.js*

```
var alert_prompt = {
init : function()
{
    alert_prompt.timedCount(0);
},
timedCount : function(c)
{
    //update the prompt message
    document.getElementById('result').value="This prompt will close in "+ (10 - c) + " seconds.";
    //if 10 seconds are over close the window
    if(c == 10)
    {
        window.close();
    }
    //update the counter
    c=c+1;
    //use the timer
    t=setTimeout(

        function()
        {
            alert_prompt.timedCount(c);
        },1000)
},
doOK : function()
{
    //code that you want to run when save button is pressed 
    return true;
},

doCancel : function()
{
    //code that you want to run when cancel button is pressed 
    return true;
},
};
window.addEventListener("load", alert_prompt.init, false);
```

3) Instead of showing the alert prompt as earlier use this statement:

```
openDialog("chrome://hello/content/alert_prompt.xul","alert_prompt","modal");
```

If you want to return a value from the alert box such as which button was pressed you can do so in the same way as discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172333/pass-variable-values-from-child-xul-window-to-parent-xul-window-using-javascript/7172692#7172692)

I am not sure about the positioning of a modal window so you may want to ask that in a separate question.

Comment: This will do for my requirement. Thank you. BY any chance do you know how to pop-up an alert message or notification pop-up if a user types more than 30 characters in the Firefox browser(html text-box editor of any website in Firefox for example in gmail text-box)?

Comment: I can't think of a straight forward way. Maybe you want to see if anyone can come up with a quick reply. I shall give it some thought.

Comment: This Firefox plugin has the function, when ever you type something in the Firefox browser after some seconds it w'll be display a pop-up message in the Status-bar! https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/