# How to add image in alert or in propmts.alert using JavaScript XUL

Tags: javascript, image, alert, xul, prompt

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPromptService#prompt_example
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Alerts_and_Notifications

Mozilla XUL offers various types of alert and notification box messages. But, still why can't we have an image in the alert message?

```
    var prompts = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"]
                        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPromptService);

   prompts.alert(null, contact, "No Email Address")
```

The above code to display an alert with custom title message. When we check the `nsIPromptService`, it give various options but still there is no possibility of adding an image according to my knowledge.

When we check the popup in XUL, `we can add an image` but the alert will display in the corner of the system because it's using the `nsIAlertsService` and the display of this pop-up is platform independent.

Would it be possible to have an image in the alert box or in the prompts.alert box using JavaScript in XUL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a custom alert dialog as discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196269/close-prompt-alert-box-automatically-with-10seconds-in-xul-javascript/7202199#7202199) ?

XUL for the alert with image may be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css" type="text/css"?>
<dialog id="alertprompt" title="Alert"
   xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   buttons="accept"
   buttonlabelaccept="Ok"
   height="160"
   width="260"
   ondialogaccept="return alert_prompt.doOK();">

   <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://hello/content/alert_prompt.js"/>
    <label id="title" value="Title may go here!" align="center" class="header"/>
    <html:table>
        <html:tr>
            <html:td>
                <html:img src="Firefoxlogo.png" width="30" height="30"/>
            </html:td>
            <html:td>
                <label id="result" value="This place will display your message." align="center"/>
            </html:td>
        </html:tr>
    </html:table>
</dialog>
```

It will look something like:

[image]

Does it meet your requirement?

Comment: :I want to make a alert with the custom title and a variable to display my message & finally i want to have an image?

Comment: Updated answer to include code for the alert with message, title and image.

Comment: Thanks. I have a variable value, how can i put that variable to the title of this alert page?

Comment: `document.getElementById('title').value= title_variable` use this in the js code linked to this file.

Comment: Either you can include this script file in the above XUL and then set the title as you get the value of contact or you can pass the value of this variable to the alert window. First one would be easier but depends on the flow of control.

Comment: OK, i'll do it. Thank you. Please go to sleep it's time to sleep. Have a nice sleep.